# show/hide rows with special conditions

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with this markup:

```
<table>
    <tr class="odd"><td>Product 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="even"><td>Product 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td>Product 3</td></tr>
    <tr class="even"><td>Product 4</td></tr>       
</table>
```

Every table row is a product and some products have more information. So in this case a table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr class="odd"><td>Product 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="even"><td>Product 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="even"><td>Information 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="even"><td>Information 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td>Product 3</td></tr>
    <tr class="even"><td>Product 4</td></tr>       
</table>
```

I wan't to hide the rows with the product information, and show it after a click on the product row.

I tried this with the following Javascript function and onlick="":

```
function showHide(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if( el && el.style.visibility == 'hidden')    
        el.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
    else 
        el.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}
```

But the problem is I don't know how to target only the information rows of the product I've clicked on. It would be easy if I could change the markup, but this markup is generated, so I only can solve it with Javascript.

Is ist possible to solve this problem? I have created a fiddle, so it's easier to deliver a quick solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/emjay__/8B3M4/

Comment: you are using class and selecting id, `class="even"`, `document.getElementById(id)`

Comment: make it simple (i say not use table for design), make another level to this sub menu (another table/element), so the main menu don't stay a mess with the submenus

Comment: here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/9tQUu/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure JS method:

http://jsfiddle.net/8B3M4/13/

```
    var current_class = 'odd';
    var current_index = 0;
    var pairs = [];
    // Loop through each td
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        // Pair the products with their information based on the class
        if (row.getAttribute('class') !== current_class) {
            current_index++;
            current_class = row.getAttribute('class');
        }
        // Set up the pairing
        if (pairs[current_index] === undefined) {
            // A new pair in sights
            pairs[current_index] = {
                'product': row.cells[0],
                'info': []
            }
            row.cells[0].onclick = function(ci) {
                return function() {
                    for (var j = 0; j < pairs[ci].info.length; j++) {
                        var cell = pairs[ci].info[j];
                        if (cell.style.display == 'none') {
                            cell.style.display = '';
                        }
                        else {
                            cell.style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }(current_index);
        }
        else {
            // Add more info to the object
            pairs[current_index].info.push(row.cells[0]);
            console.log(row.cells[0].style.display);
            row.cells[0].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's nice, but isn't var current_class = 'odd'; limiting this to all even lines?

Comment: current_class is changed when it encounters a tr which has a different class. So when the class changes to 'even' then current_class is changed from 'odd' to 'even'. This is basically a more complex and verbose version of @danko's answer

Comment: I've updated my answer to be pure JS. Danko has the jQuery version down to a tee.

Answer (score 4):

Hi for this i propose you a solution with Jquery : **http://jsfiddle.net/8B3M4/9/**

- First hide all your elements with just CSS : matching all elements preceeded by the same class name.

  ```
  tr.even + .even {
   display:none;
  }
  tr.odd + .odd {
   display:none;
  }
  ```
- Second this function wich show / hide the elements:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr.even').click(function (){
      $(this).nextUntil('.odd').toggle();
    })
  })
  ```

Comment: I think it would be better to also hide the information with js rather than css because then it would fall back to displaying all the information for users who have js disabled.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you are using class and selecting ID.

On the second hand, I would use display property.

```
if( el && el.style.visibility == 'hidden')    
    el.style.display = 'block'; 
else 
    el.style.display = 'none';
```

On the third invisible hand, you still have "a lot" of work to do to get it running.

Answer (score 1):

This is working (s. http://jsfiddle.net/S7gTA/3/)

```
var lastClass = 0; 
var lastIndex = 0;
$('tr').each(function(index, element){ // get each tr on the page, change the selector to #%TABLEID% > tr if this should work only for a specific table

  if($(this).attr("class") != lastClass) // class change from odd to even or even to odd?
  {
   lastClass = $(this).attr("class"); // set current "mother" class
   lastIndex = index; // store the index of the "mother"
   $(this).addClass("mother").attr("rel", index) // now the mother is able to hide or show all the element with the class info-for-%index% *1
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).addClass("info-for-"+lastIndex).hide(); 
  }

});

$( '.mother' ).bind("click", function(){ $('.info-for-'+$(this).attr("rel")).toggle();  });
```